# yii2 pjax reload issue

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

This is my reload code for pjax:

```
$('form#action-filter-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $("#pjax-action-filter-form").on("pjax:end", function() { 
      $("#pjax-action-filter-grid").show(); 
      $.pjax.reload({container:"#pjax-action-filter-grid"});  
   });
});
```

What i am trying to achieve is to reload the gridview after submitting the search form. But on form submission 3 calls are fired as seen from console in which second one is cancelled and the page gets reloaded.Is there any way to reload only the gridview on form submit. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide your view files like index.php ,_search.php

Comment: I somehow got it working by setting async:false in the reload code. Thanks!